# PayPal Delayed Chain Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to write C# code to process delayed PayPal chained adaptive payments.  After reading their 293 page PDF twice, I am totally bewildered at where to start.  So much explanation from a top level but nothing from down under. Does anyone know how to do this start to finish who can point me to a resource, an outline of steps or just pray for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a bit to the PayPal Adaptive Payments API but I found a really, really good head start by downloading this C# example solution: [Paypal adaptive payments using .NET (C#)](http://xadaptivepayments.codeplex.com/releases/view/56681)

Anyone struggling should find solice there.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-dotnet/blob/master/AdaptivePayments/PaySample.cs to pass action = PAY_PRIMARY

Comment: That's one way to use the PayPal Adaptive Payments API but there are several others. See my answer after plenty of struggle, below.